# dnsmasq.leases write wrong parameter (opensuse)

Tags: configuration, opensuse, suse, dnsmasq, mac-address

I'm running platform tests on several computers. The dnsmasq.leases is writing a strange parameter when I test with Opensuse OS. Can anybody help me?

```
1681465068 00:04:5f:41:3a:d9 55.0.168.110 cpru201 ff:5f:41:3a:d9:00:01:00:01:2b:c6:cd:17:00:04:5f:41:3a:d9

1681465864 c4:00:ad:53:80:1c 55.0.168.171 prueba ff:ad:53:80:1c:00:01:00:01:2b:c7:e4:f1:c4:00:ad:53:80:1c
```

Normal parameters:

```
1681464984 c4:00:ad:1e:2d:e0 55.0.168.136 cpru200 01:c4:00:ad:1e:2d:e0
```